# How do I implement a trait for all lifetimes of the struct?

Tags: rust

I reduced my problem to this minimum reproducible example ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=71041743fe09999b65923276138d60be)):

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;

pub trait D<'a> {
    type A: A + 'a;
    type B: B + 'a;
}

pub trait A {
    fn a(self);
}

pub trait B {
    fn b(self);
}

pub struct AA {}

impl A for AA {
    fn a() {}
}

pub struct BB<'a> {
    phantom: PhantomData<&'a u8>,
}

impl<'a> B for BB<'a> {
    fn b() {}
}

impl<'a: 'd, 'd> D<'d> for E<'a> {
    type A = AA;
    type B = BB<'a>;
}

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct E<'a> {
    phantom: PhantomData<&'a u8>,
}

pub struct S<D_T>
where
    D_T: for<'d> D<'d>,
{
    a: D_T,
}

pub enum R<'a> {
    RR(S<E<'a>>),
}
```

I'm getting

```
error: implementation of `D` is not general enough
  --> src/lib.rs:48:8
   |
3  | / pub trait D<'a> {
4  | |     type A: A + 'a;
5  | |     type B: B + 'a;
6  | | }
   | |_- trait `D` defined here
...
48 |       RR(S<E<'a>>),
   |          ^^^^^^^^ implementation of `D` is not general enough
   |
   = note: `D<'0>` would have to be implemented for the type `E<'a>`, for any lifetime `'0`...
   = note: ...but `D<'_>` is actually implemented for the type `E<'1>`, for some specific lifetime `'1`
```

I have a small idea why it's happening, but is there a way to have `BB` with a reference in this case? Most of the things here are from a library I don't control so I cannot change them.

Comment: I tried to fix up the code so it compiles with the same errors, but there are various types missing, and `RxToken` appears to both a trait and a type.

Comment: @PeterHall thank you very much! Unfortunately I couldn't isolate the problem. However, if you happen to have docker and visual studio and the `ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers` plugin on it, simply opening the project and clicking "open in container" will give you a completely ready environment to compile my code https://github.com/lucaszanella/smoltcp_cpp_interface/tree/1e55dd6e4454404dcdefb0fef31fd81e1dc06907

Comment: @Shepmaster take a look, just reduced to a MRE

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs I don't think I've understand your real use case but does this kind a hack solves your problem? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e0c1030dfb1c3d75e42221945191c61b

Answer (score 1):

The struct `S` would need `D` to be implemented for `D_T` for all lifetimes, which would also include `'static`. Now, `S` is used in enum `R` with type `E`, with a generic lifetime `'a`. If `'a` is anything but `'static`, type `B` of struct `D` could not possibly be implemented containing a non-static reference. This simply can not work, and something needs changing.

The first option would be to make enum `R` use `'static` lifetime in `E`, but that would be rather unpractical.

Another option would be to remove the `D_T: for<'d> D<'d>` requirement from `S`, adding an additional lifetime argument, and adding phantom data to the structure.

If neither of them are possible, and I am not missing anything, there is not much you can do without resorting to runtime checks, and making the `BB` type not be lifetime bound (using reference counting). You would need to use either `Rc<BB>` as `B`, or have a `Rc<SomeType>` inside the `BB`. The former would look something like this:

```rust
impl<'d> D<'d> for E {
    type A = AA;
    type B = Rc<BB>;
}

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct E {
    ref_counted: Rc<BB>
}

pub struct BB {

}

impl B for Rc<BB> {
    fn b(mut self) {
        if let Some(bb) = Rc::get_mut(&mut self) {
            //code with BB's MUTABLE REFERENCE
        }
    }
}


pub struct S<D_T>
where
    D_T: for<'d> D<'d>,
{
    a: D_T
}


pub enum R {
    RR(S<E>),
}
```

The `B` implementation uses a mutable reference of the underlying value in the method, if you would like to consume the value inside `ref_counted` instead, you would have to try something like this:

```rust
impl B for Rc<BB> {
    fn b(mut self) {
        match Rc::try_unwrap(self) {
            Ok(bb) => {
                //code with BB's VALUE
            },
            Err(bbrc) => {
                //we can not consume the value in self, because
                //there was a reference held somewhere else in the code
                //here lies code with BB's reference counted pointer
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to hold a reference without having to use lifetimes? Could you show me?